# how limit docker cpu frequency by gigahertz

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cpu

I want to know how can I limit my docker containers CPU frequency by Gigahertz/GHz.
I don't want to limit CPU only by the number of cores.

```
--cpus=<value>  
--cpu-period=<value>    
--cpu-quota=<value> 
--cpuset-cpus   
--cpu-shares
```

this onnes not helpfull

Comment: What would this mean?  You want the processor's core speed to slow down while your process is running, or for it to skip every third clock cycle?  What's the higher-level goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: i just wanna limit containers to cpu cores and cpu frequency/ghz

Comment: That's not something that you can change on a per-process or per-container basis.  I'm not clear why you would want to change it at all.

Comment: I guess he just wants consistent performance for replicas of the same container

Answer (score 3):

Limiting container CPU usage by Hz is not possible using Docker, the options to limit CPU usage are described in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#cpu).

On [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#resource-units-in-kubernetes), Limits and requests for CPU resources are measured in *cpu* units. One cpu, in Kubernetes, is equivalent to **1 vCPU/Core** for cloud providers and **1 hyperthread** on bare-metal Intel processors.

Comment: what is the frequency of the vCPU? a fixed number? of case by case depending the particular node that my pod gets allocated to?

Comment: It depends on the frequency of the node your pod gets allocated.

Comment: I see, so if I am running a heterogeneous k8s cluster, then there is no way to consistently predict container performance, containers will perform based on if they get lucky and get allocated to a nice node. is that correct?

Comment: That's true, however if you really want a pod to be allocated in a node with better CPU for example, you can use [Node Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/).